Can i combine contain and startswith in order to match two columns from one dataframe to another's master column?
Master dataframe filled with a specific match's players and statistics.
34 columns and variable number of rows.
Column "Player" has full names



Player
Goals
Assists




Dominic Calvert-Lewin
1
1


Beto
2
0


Jarrad Branthwaite
0
1


Jack Harrison
0
0



Snippet dataframe automatically created, displays only players with a referee note (Yelllow cards, Red Cards).
Consists of 3 columns. The problem is that First Name is either a full name, initial letter or blank.



First Name
Last Name
Cause




D
Calvert-Lewin
Foul



Beto
Time Wasting


Jack
Harrison




What i want to achieve:
Match "First Name" probably using startswith along "Last Name" using contains, with Player in master df.
If both colums match add a column to Snippet df with fullnames.
Expected dataframe:



Player
Cause




Dominic Calvert-Lewin
Foul


Beto
Time Wasting


Jack Harrison




So far i only had one to one matching:
pat1 = '('+'|'.join(Snippet['Last Name'])+')'
Master["Yellow"] = Master['Player'].str.extract(pat1)[0].map(Snippet.set_index('Last Name')['Cause'].to_dict()).fillna('')


Sorry, I can't follow the description of the problem at all. It certainly doesn't help that it's full of sentence fragments rather than complete sentences. To be clear: are the "master dataframe" and the "snippet dataframe" both inputs to the problem? For the exact shown inputs, exactly what should the output be? As is, I can't even tell whether you expect the result to be a DataFrame, or just what.

Are there players with the same last name in your data? If not, just match the last name.

This problem doesn't have a generic solution, as explained in the link below. You'd have to tell us what assumptions you are willing to make about the data. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

@Joooeey Yes, there are often duplicates in last names.

Okay, can you at least assume that no last names in your data contain spaces, that all the names are written from left to right (e.g. no Arabic script), and that the last name is never written before the first name(s)? What other assumptions can you make?

@Joooeey Not spaces, Not Arabic and not swapped names. Both dataframes are scraped fro the same source but while master is scraped from table, snippet created from match's timeline and often the first name is croped to fit in.

I have edited the post by adding the desired output.

If you have these two dataframes:
df_master

                  Player  Goals  Assists
0  Dominic Calvert-Lewin      1        1
1                   Beto      2        0
2     Jarrad Branthwaite      0        1
3          Jack Harrison      0        0


df_snippet

  First Name      Last Name         Cause
0          D  Calvert-Lewin          Foul
1        NaN           Beto  Time Wasting
2       Jack       Harrison           NaN
3      Hello          World           NaN

Then you can do:
df_snippet["First Name"] = df_snippet["First Name"].fillna("")

out = []
for _, row in df2.iterrows():
    m1 = df_master["Player"].str.startswith(row["First Name"])
    m2 = df_master["Player"].str.endswith(row["Last Name"])

    m = m1 & m2

    if m.any():
        out.append(df_master.loc[m.idxmax(), "Player"])
    else:
        out.append(None)

df_snippet["Player"] = out
print(df_snippet)

Prints:
  First Name      Last Name         Cause                 Player
0          D  Calvert-Lewin          Foul  Dominic Calvert-Lewin
1                      Beto  Time Wasting                   Beto
2       Jack       Harrison           NaN          Jack Harrison
3      Hello          World           NaN                   None

